# Can I add error monitoring (real temperature vs predicted)?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am a beginner in ML  and I want to be able to predict temperature using real time temperature from a database. After I train the model, I want to be able to monitor the error and to add a threshold. In case the error between the real temperature vs predicted is bigger than my threshold, I want to retrain. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible the way of doing it depends on what you are using as a framework. you would have to compare your minimized error to that treshold after each prediction. And DON'T forget to predict from your test dataset and not from the one you used for training.